# How do I compare dates in angular ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
<div ng-class"{'has-error': myInputForm.$valid}">
  ...other stuff....
</div>
```

I love this kind of validation and the above code works. What I would like to do is compare two date values so it would look like this....

```
<div ng-class"{'has-error': myStartDate < eventStartDate}">
  ...other stuff....
</div>
```

This doesn't work and neither does this, but it would be nice if it did

```
<div ng-class"{'has-error': moment(myStartDate).isBefore(eventStartDate)}">
  ...other stuff....
</div>
```

I could make a function to return the class based on parameters

```
<div ng-class"getClass(myStartDate,eventStartDate)">
  ...other stuff....
</div>
```

but I have other things that need to be checked, so I would like to do this inline. Let me know what ideas you have and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have "other things" doesn't it make more sense to put it all in functions in your JS and not clutter up your HTML code? That would be my answer regardless of what you theoretically can do.

Comment: 3rd is one of the good approach to go it..keeping expression inside the controller as method would make more sense..as those method can be easily tested unit test  cases.

Comment: the checks should not be done inline, they belong in the javascript. The checks should be in JS and an attribute should be assigned based on those checks. Then that attribute would determine what class to assign in ng-class.

Comment: @PankajParkar, why would the third one be the best? shouldn't these checks be done in JS?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Make you html more readable in the sense..rather than writing whole code on html..do expression/comparison on the JS side, because the controller code will be testable using unit test to ensure its quality and functionality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the equal sign after `ng-class`.

You've got `ng-class"{'has-error': myStartDate < eventStartDate}">`.  It should be `ng-class="{'has-error': myStartDate < eventStartDate}"`.  The `=` is very important!

Also, make sure your dates are really dates and not strings.

Here's a little demo page that works for me.  You can adjust My Start Date downward and see the has-error class get applied.

Good Luck!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myStartDate = new Date(2015, 6, 29);
        $scope.eventStartDate = new Date(2015, 6, 28);
      }]);
    </script>
    <style> .has-error { background-color: red; } </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form ng-controller="MyController">
      <label for="start-in">My Start Date</label>
      <input id="start-in" type="date" ng-model="myStartDate">
      <label for="event-in">Event Start Date</label>
      <input id="event-in" type="date" ng-model="eventStartDate">
      <div ng-class="{'has-error': myStartDate < eventStartDate}">
        {{myStartDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}} -- {{eventStartDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}}
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```